# Is Temporary Dead Zone an official term in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

While learning JavaScript, I heard the term for Temporary Dead Zone. However, no relevant term was found in ECMAScript.

Is Temporary Dead Zone an official term for ECMAScript?

I want to listen to other people's opinions and have confidence.

Comment: No. It's "*temporal"*, not "*temporary*"

Answer (score 1):

The official ECMAScript specification does not contain the words "Temporal Dead Zone", TDZ, or similar. To be honest, TDZ tried to sneak in, but was operatively removed: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1905.

The specification uses its own terminology:

https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations

Spec:

> `let` and `const` declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's `LexicalEnvironment`. The variables are created when their containing `Environment Record` is instantiated...

Plain words: this is called "hoisting" - declarations from the code like `let x; const y = 2;` are hoisted to the start of the scope (`LexicalEnvironment`). Only declarations, i.e. `x, y`, not their values.

Spec:

> ...but may not be accessed in any way until the variable's `LexicalBinding` is evaluated.

Plain words: `x` cannot be accessed until the line `let x;` is executed; `y` cannot be accessed until the line `const y = 2;` is executed.

Spec:

> A variable defined by a `LexicalBinding` with an `Initializer` is assigned the value of its `Initializer`'s `AssignmentExpression` when the `LexicalBinding` is evaluated, not when the variable is created.

Plain words: `x` will become its value `undefined` only when the line `let x;` is executed; `y` will become its value `2` only when the line `const y = 2;` is executed.

https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-declarative-environment-records-getbindingvalue-n-s

Spec:

> The `GetBindingValue` concrete method of a Declarative Environment Record ... returns either a normal completion containing an ECMAScript language value or a throw completion. It returns the value of its bound identifier whose name is `N`. If the binding exists but is uninitialized a `ReferenceError` is thrown

Plain words: when we are trying to access our hoisted `x` or `y` before the line of code `let x; const y = 2;` is actually executed, `ReferenceError` is thrown. This is what we call TDZ: accessing the variable that is in the scope (remember hoisting) but not yet initialized throws `ReferenceError`.

Note that the specification gives no name for such complex behavior, and splits it into separate pieces. Someone has invented the term "Temporal Dead Zone" while explaining this process, to make it more understandable and to make it *identifiable* - now anyone can say "TDZ" and everyone understands what they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you don't mean temporal instead of temporary?

Temporal Dead Zone is the period of time during which the let and const declarations cannot be accessed.

https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone-in-javascript

Comment: I wonder if it is a term used in the official specification of ECMAScript.

Comment: @조승희 did you *check* [the official specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/) for it?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find the term Temporary Dead Zone.

Comment: @조승희 Right. Which means it's not a term in the spec. For the record, the *correct* name is as the answer says Termpor**al** Dead Zone. That is also not in the spec. Yet, I don't really see how that really helps. The term *is* well understood and well defined. It's just not in the specifications.